# Fine-tune CNN with different number of classes

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I'm trying to fine-tune a PASCAL-VOC trained faster-RCNN model on my own 30 classes dataset.

Reference model: [link](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/models/pascal_voc/ZF/fast_rcnn/train.prototxt)

Of course when I change cls_score and bbox_pred num_output to 30 and 120 instead of 21 and 84 respectively, these layers' weights aren't loaded and I need to change the layers' names.
I wonder if there is a way to preserve the data learned in the FC layers for different number of classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Berkley repo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Borrowing-Weights-from-a-Pretrained-Network), this should be simple.

You need to match your layer name with the reference model's layers you want. For example, if you want the weights from a reference model's `ip1` layer, then your model should have the same name:

```
layer {
  name: "ip1"
  ...
```

Layers in your model with different names will be randomly initialized, or according to the scheme you've decided. When training, to borrow the weights from `theirModel.caffemodel`, you launch your model as so:

```
caffe train —solver ourSolver.prototxt —weights theirModel.caffemodel
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I think I didn't answer your question at all. If a fully connected layer is a 100 x 10 matrix, you cannot use the weights for a 100 x 20 matrix for example. The weights don't mean anything in the new context. It's best to initialize the new layer randomly.

Comment: Thanks @vega. I indeed asked if the (in your example) 100 x 10 can have any meaning for new classes / another shape.

Comment: It won't have any meaning. So the original output layer 100x10 would be scrapped and you would initialize a new 100x20 layer. However, you can keep all the pretrained lower layers from the other model, those could be beneficial. Does that answer your question?